# how to do synchronization between two linux modules?

Tags: linux, synchronization, kernel, linux-device-driver, mutex

I have a core driver implemented in linux(driver/mfd/. This core driver has two mfd cells each is going to touch the portion of the mapped memory. These mfd cells are separate modules ( drivers/char/ and drivers/char/). But before accessing their portion of the memory , there is a shared register which we need to touch (mapped) . This has to be done in proper sequence some sort of synchronization is required. Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Comment: It should be one driver by description you gave. Otherwise you need a lot of additional work to make *shared* register works between drivers.

Comment: Depending on whether the code is allowed to sleep or not, you can use a mutex or a spin-lock to synchronize access. If only the core driver should touch the shared register, you can provide functions in the core driver to do the locking and unlocking, and call those functions from the other modules. (You'll need to export these functions with `EXPORT_SYMBOL(func)` or `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(func)` so the other modules can call them.)

Comment: Thanks it helped

Comment: As soon as you realize that both modules get linked together as if they were one (when you install them), the whole problem is likely to disappear. It's as if you had two functions in the same module, i.e., it's just packaging. BTW, you can even link non-exported symbols yourself, simply by using kallsyms_lookup_name(symbol).